# Perforce - Recover deleted file

Tags: version-control, perforce

I opened a file (`p4 edit`) and made few changes to it. I deleted (`rm -rf`) the directory which contained this file followed by a `p4 sync -f` to bring back the depot files (in hopes of getting rid of a lot of untracked/generated files in the directory).

However, it helped me only partially. While I was able to get rid of of the undesired files, the `sync` step could not bring back the edited file.

I can see that the file is in opened state with `p4 opened`, but I can't seem to find a way to bring back this opened file along with my changes.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited files are not stored on the server; they are only stored locally.  Since you removed the modified file with `rm -rf` you cannot get it back (unless the file was backed up by another process, such as a netapp .snapshot directory).

The server keeps track of the state of files but the changes are not stored until you submit.

Comment: Prior to submit, you can 'p4 shelve' your opened files. Then they are stored on the server but not submitted.